# union in c++ with a single non trivial type

Tags: c++

I have a simple struct that can carry either a result, or error, never both.
Both are the same type, but I want two members just for clarity.
From reading [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) it looks like the following code snippet would be valid c++?
With a placement delete in the union destructor to tidy up the `non trivial` class (std::string in this instance).

```
struct Result {
  union {
    std::string resultText;
    std::string errorText;
    ~(){ resultText.~string();}
  };
};
```

It looks like, to use this, the containing struct would need to implement the rule-of-5 members to explicitly copy/move resultText.

Comment: This is such a weird use case for an union - what's wrong with a single private strings and two getters (like `getResultText()` and `getErrorText()`)? You could even add a debug-only flag to make sure you're getting the correct text.

Comment: You could also have a simple struct with a `std::string` and a `bool` (or even enum) to indicate the result is an error or an actual result. I have to agree with @VittorioRomeo, it's a very weird idea to use a union for such.

Comment: BTW, your struct actually misses a discriminator what to use from the union actually.

Comment: As c++ doesn't have strong `typedef`, you may wrap your `std::string` in classes (`struct Ok {std::string text;}; struct Error {std::string text;};`), and then use some variant class (`using Result = boost::variant<Ok, Error>`).

Comment: Is there usually ever a good use case for a union in c++ code? This is, I admit, an exercise in doing something stupid that I would never want to see in production code. But its interesting in that for most of my c++ career I just never even considered that a union with non trivial members would be supported by the language at all.

Answer (score 1):

A union is just going to decrease readability of your code. And depending on how you use it will increase maintenance too. Actually the fact that you mentioned "implementing the rule of 5" despite having a `std::string` member suggests that your class is going to be a nightmare to maintain.

I would look at these options (not enough detail in the question to determine what would be best):

- Use an exception. You can make a custom exception by deriving from `std::exception`
- Use `Boost.Optional`.

  ```
  boost::optional<std::string> do_something() { ... };

  std::string result = do_something().value_or("error!");
  ```

Comment: You may want to mention that `std::optional` does not yet exist in the latest c++ standard.